# Import sklearn doesn’t exist on my replit

Tags: python, replit, replit-database

For some odd reason when I do “import sklearn” it says ModuleNotFound or something like that. Can anyone please help?

I tried going online and using bash to fix it but still didn’t work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a  shell in the workspace with `ctrl-shift-s`
on mac `command-shift-s` command prompt and run this command, it will install scikit

> pip install scikit-learn

Comment: This doesnt work

Comment: what IDE are you using ?

Comment: I did “from sklearn import tree” and it says it isn’t a module and I tried your way on the replit shell and said no directory

Comment: I use replit as my IDE

Comment: i edited the response you must open replit shell and run the command, also replit install package dynamically try to add the import in the top of the file